# Centos Apache server doesnt seem to redirect

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I am trying to set up my apache server. So far I have the following apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/system_learningbank/
ServerName www.learningbypower.dk
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

(You can try it out by going to www.learnbypower.dk)

The login screen works fine. However, when I log in it seems as if it's redirecting to another folder where my old system was.

Can anyone tell me what I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: Login with invalid credential **500 Internal server** error occurred. Are you sure you are properly redirecting to your new location within PHP too? Better check your logs

Comment: @RahilWazir it works on my local linux computer

Comment: This is an error in your application configuration. The application is failing. Check the logs.

Comment: @beiller note that the fav icon changes this means it is redirecting in a wrong way isnt it?

Comment: No there is no redirect taking place. There is a 500 internal server error like Rahil pointed out.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen The PHP version on Local and RemoTe server may differ

Comment: @RahilWazir could it be a mod that is not enabled on the server?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Assuming...? Why don't you just check **LOGS**?

Comment: @RahilWazir it cant seem to find the logs

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Try `/home/{user}/public_html/error_log`

Comment: @RahilWazir i dont have a public_html folder

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Ok then this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in your application configuration. The application is failing. Check the logs. Likely its caused by a syntax error or, maybe missing libraries like GD, etc.

Look at the log file:

```
logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
```